# PHP select then edit session

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm busy making a website, but now I'm stuck; this is my code

```
    <select onchange="window.location = '/'  + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <?php
    $hosts = $mysql->query("SELECT id FROM user_host WHERE uid = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $hostsFetch = $hosts->fetch_assoc();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['siteid'])) {
    $_SESSION['siteid'] = $hostsFetch['id'];
    }

    $host = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM user_host WHERE uid = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    while($item = $host->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <option value="./home" <?php echo ($_SESSION['siteid'] == $item['id'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>><?php echo $item['name'] . ' - '. $item['domein']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select>
```

Now, when he selects an account, he needs to go into that account. How can I get that working?

Comment: U need to add more details like ..... wait for it !! What is your problem ? what is it not working etc...

Comment: When i select a other account, i press at it, and it stays at the default account

Comment: past your -generated- html output please

Comment: Where can i find that? never heard of it

Comment: right click on your webbrowser on the page and then click on "show source". NB : I don't need all your page just the select.

Comment: <select onchange="window.location = '/'  + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
   <option value="./home" selected="">Jesper0100 - jesper.nl</option>
   <option value="./home">one2xs - one2xs.com</option>

</select>

Comment: just echo the query. And paste it here

Comment: try removing `'/' +` from your code

Comment: you have "./home" in all the values of your option that what you want ? So the onchange will always redirect you on ./home

Comment: @Su4p he appends `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: But i want to set the session siteid to the id in select and then go to /home

Comment: you need to learn the basics about client/server programming. In order to make this work as you intented you need to make ajax OR setting something like that in your options value="./home?session=".$item['id'] and on your home you'll be able to set the session with something like this $_SESSION['siteid'] = $_GET['session']

Comment: try to do this <option value="./home?site_id=<?php echo $item['id' ?> />. And on your home put this : print_r($_GET);$_SESSION['site_id'] = $_GET['site_id] . You maybe will understand what I'm trying to make you do.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved,' or any variation thereof, to your question's title. If an answer has solved your problem mark that answer as 'accepted' by clicking the check-mark beside the text of the answer itself. If you've solved the problem yourself, then please post your solution as an answer (**not** as part of the question) and, when you're able, accept that answer. Please see: "[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)" and "[Is it OK to add \[solved\] to the title of a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/)"

Answer (score 1):

with the html/javascript code you are using, you will always go to your `/home` directory.
when you select something out of your menu the `onchange`- event is triggered. this takes the value of the selected `option`. hence the value in your `options` is hard-coded, it will always point to the same page which doesn't change anything.

```
<select onchange="window.location = '/'  + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="./home" .....>
```

so you need to add something to differentiate between the chosen `options`, like for example:

```
<option value="./home/index.php?user_host=<?php echo $item['id']?>" .....>
```

and in your php/mysql code you have to react using the `GET` var you transmitted, for example:

```
$mysql->query("SELECT something FROM table WHERE user_host = ".$_GET['user_host']);
```